# Concatenating 2nd element of a tuple in a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples, concatenation

I have a list like this:

```
[(1,[2]), (1,[3]), (1,[4]), (2,[1]), (2,[2]), (3,[1])]
```

what I want is a function that starts with the 1st element in the list and if it finds any other element in the list with a similar (fst) of the tuple then it concatenates the (snd) of the found element to the (snd) of the first element. In the example shown above, the end result would be the following list:

```
[(1,[2,3,4]), (2,[1,2]), (3,[1])]
```

I have tried many options with no success. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? You might want to play with ``groupBy ((==) `on
` fst)`` using `Data.List.groupBy` and `Data.Function.on`

Comment: Thanks, but not giving exactly the result I want. Running the function you suggested gave me on the same list above the following list:

[[(1,[2]),(1,[3]),(1,[4])],[(2,[1]),(2,[2])],[(3,[1])]]

while I want is:

[(1,[2,3,4]), (1,[1,2]), (3,[1])]

Comment: well the idea was obviously that you start there and see if you can complete it yourself ... but alas you got 2 spoilers below ;)

Comment: hehe. You are right. Thanks Carsten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that [`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) will not group if the keys of the same value are not consecutive. For example:

```
\> groupBy (==) [1, 2, 1]
[[1],[2],[1]]
```

So you need to make sure you pass in a sorted list. 
An alternative would be to use [`Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map.html) and a right fold:

```
import Data.Map (empty, alter, toList)

fun :: (Foldable t, Ord k) => t (k, [a]) -> [(k, [a])]
fun = toList . foldr go empty
    where
    go (k, x) acc  = alter (inc x) k acc
    inc x Nothing  = Just x
    inc x (Just y) = Just (x ++ y)
```

which will work regardless of the list being sorted or not:

```
\> fun [(1,[2]), (1,[3]), (1,[4]), (2,[1]), (2,[2]), (3,[1])]
[(1,[2,3,4]),(2,[1,2]),(3,[1])]

\> fun [(3,[1]), (1,[2]), (2,[1]), (1,[3]), (2,[2]), (1,[4])]
[(1,[2,3,4]),(2,[1,2]),(3,[1])]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import Data.List (groupBy)
import Data.Function (on)
import Control.Arrow ((***))

f  = map ((head *** concat) . unzip) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
```

.

```
> let l =  [(1,[2]), (1,[3]), (1,[4]), (2,[1]), (2,[2]), (3,[1])]

> groupBy ((==) `on` fst) l
[[(1,[2]),(1,[3]),(1,[4])],[(2,[1]),(2,[2])],[(3,[1])]]

> map unzip $ groupBy ((==) `on` fst) l
[([1,1,1],[[2],[3],[4]]),([2,2],[[1],[2]]),([3],[[1]])]
```

You can use (***) from Control.Arrow to manipulate tuple

```
> (pred *** succ) (4,5)
(3,6)

> let f  = map ((head *** concat) . unzip) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) 
> f l
[(1,[2,3,4]),(2,[1,2]),(3,[1])]
```

Comment: Thanks. This in fact solves my original structure which has the signature [(Int,Int,Int),[Int]). When I raised the question I tried to pose a rather simpler structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
Prelude> :m + Data.Function Data.List    
Prelude> let xs = [(1,[2]), (1,[3]), (1,[4]), (2,[1]), (2,[2]), (3,[1])]
Prelude> map (\lst -> (fst $ head lst, concat $ map snd lst)) (groupBy ((==) `on` fst) xs)
[(1,[2,3,4]),(2,[1,2]),(3,[1])]
```

Comment: Thanks as well. It worked also on my original structure.